# error during call perl script in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, perl

I want to write trigger that after insert call Perl script like following code:

```
create trigger example after insert on radacct 

for each row begin

set @rs=sys_exec(CONCAT('/usr/bin/perl','/usr/bin/p2.pl'));

end
```

My trigger successfully runs but my Perl script does not run and value of `@rs` is zero after insert.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer your question but I will offer an alternative way of doing that and it doesn't include UDFs.

Create a trigger that populates a run queue instead of calling the UDF. 
Have the perl script poll and empty that queue instead of being called from the trigger.
This makes a much more robust system.

When adding a UDF to a trigger you are compromising the database and introducing a external part that might not behave in the same predictable time as a normal trigger would do. Mind that the entire call is waiting for your sys_exec to finish.

Comment: I want know when one record inserted to radacct table and get that record inside my program eg bash or perl.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agreed with Andreas's answer above.
Triggers are usually fired after the data is commited. You might get it to work/run by adding ("&") at the end in order to have the trigger run it in the background. Something like:

```
  set @rs=sys_exec(CONCAT('/usr/bin/perl','/usr/bin/p2.pl',' &'));
```

Comment: I wrote   set @rs=sys_exec(CONCAT('/usr/bin/perl','/usr/bin/p2.pl',' &'));
but return zero. mysql version is 5.5

Answer (score 0):

try doing this.
it works for me.

```
create trigger example after insert on radacct 

for each row begin

set @rs=sys_exec(CONCAT('/usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/p2.pl &'));

end
```